# Upload array of images to server using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4

I'm using Swift4, I had uploaded image to server using this code

```
class func uploadMultipleAdvertisementImage(photos: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ sucess: Bool, _ image_id: Int)-> Void) {

    let url = URLs.uploadImages

    var images = [Data]()
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (form: MultipartFormData) in



       if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos , 0.5) {
            form.append(data, withName: "images", fileName: "photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

    }, usingThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold, to: url, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result: SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in

        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(error, false, 0)

        case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress: Progress) in
                print(progress)
            })
                .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in

                    switch response.result
                    {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                        completion(error, false, 0)

                    case .success(let value):
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print(json)
                        if(json["msg"] == "image uploaded successfully") {
                            let image_id = json["image_id"].int ?? 0
                            print("hiiiiiiiiii", image_id)
                            completion(nil, true, image_id)
                        }
                    }

                })
        }

    }
}
```

it worked successfuly, 
but I want to upload array of images to the server with name "images". 
there is any way to upload array of images to server rather than upload one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427541/swift-3-alamofire-4-upload-array-of-images-with-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload multiple images in swift using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499768/upload-multiple-images-in-swift-using-alamofire)

Comment: You can check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685210/multipart-form-data-using-alamofire/49550226#49550226

Comment: You api must be managed get of image data as an array. if that setting parameter for images for one and that overrite each image with new image come from array. contact your backend developer to manage image array

Comment: @NitinGohel no api  managed get of image data as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just nothing much need to do.
Add your

```
if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos , 0.5) {
            form.append(data, withName: "images", fileName: "photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
```

code into For loop, and rest of things AlamoFire will take care.

Comment: for i in 0..<photos.count{
if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos[i] , 0.5) {
            form.append(data, withName: "images", fileName: "photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
}
it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are getting `images: [UIImage]` in the function as a parameter. Then you just need to append all image's data into multipart form, just update the fileName for each image.

**Update your code lines as:**

```
for i in 0..<images.count {
    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos[i], 0.5) {        
        form.append(data, withName: "images", fileName: "photo\(i).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me maybe because it is not an array , the back end receive only array

Answer (score 0):

To tell server side that you are sending an array of images or videos, you have to append **an open and close square Brackets** **'[]'** to the parameter names. Good luck and happy coding.

```
public func multipartUpload(_ images: [String: UIImage], videos: [String: Data], params: [String: String], api: API, headers: HTTPHeaders, success: @escaping(Response?) -> Void, fail: @escaping(Error) -> Void) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in params {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }

        for (name, value) in images {
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value, 1)!, withName: "images[]", fileName: name, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

        for (name, value) in videos {
            multipartFormData.append(value, withName: "videos[]", fileName: name, mimeType: "video/mp4")
        }

    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: api.path, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion:{ encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON { response in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                }

                if let httpStatusCode = response.response?.statusCode, let data = response.data {
                    switch(httpStatusCode) {
                    case 200...300:
                        let mResponse = Response(json: JSON(data), resultCode: httpStatusCode)
                        return success(mResponse)
                    default:
                        let mResponse = Response(json: JSON(data), resultCode: httpStatusCode)
                        return success(mResponse)
                    }
                } else {
                    fail(CustomError(forClientErrorCode: .noDataToReturn))
                }

            }
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { progress in
                if let aProgressRing = Utility.shared.progressCircle {
                    aProgressRing.startProgress(to: CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted * 100), duration: 0.1)
                }
                print(progress)
            })
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    })
}
```